# can we bend EM waves with any fundamental force except with gravity

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

can we bend EM waves with any fundamental force except with  gravity....like a machine invented by nikola tesla

actually,wat my question is there is a auto biography of nikola tesla....he says that he invented a machine that can bend EM waves and he said he kept it secretly....when i saw it i was amazed..i actually learn quantum mechanics,statistical mechanics and general relativity..i still know that strong forces and gravity can bend light....and that machine actually bends em waves and makes any thing behind it invisible....can any force field bend em waves??

Comment: Photons interact with, for example, quarks, which means light is affected by the strong force (but only through loops, so the effect is surely negligible)

Comment: with a prism or a refraction with a more complicated shape ?

Comment: @BruceLee : magnetic field doesn't bend light and strong/weak forces act only at the nucleus level. And GR lensing is out of topic. Only remains classical optic

Comment: @igael Yup, I clarified some of the points in an answer.

Comment: actually,wat my question is there is a auto biography of nikola tesla....he says that he invented a machine that can bend EM waves and he said he kept it secretly....when i saw it i was amazed..i actually learn quantum mechanics,statistical mechanics and general relativity..i still know that strong forces and gravity can bend light

Comment: that machine actually bends em waves and makes any thing behind it invisible....can any force field bend em waves??

Comment: @SrikanthReddy it's an optical machine based on high refractive meta material

Comment: @SrikanthReddy does the machine actually functions? Please give a link.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy igael is right about his conclusions. Please see the edited answer for more details.

Comment: "fundamental forces", at least the strong and the weak, don't actually produce force fields in the classical sense. This question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Glass fibers. They make really nice lamps and art objects that bend light.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> can we bend EM waves with any fundamental force except with gravity

Yes, with electromagnetism. It's much stronger than gravity. It takes the huge mass-energy of the Sun to bend a light wave by only 1.75 arcseconds. See Professor Ned Wright of UCLA talking about that [here](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/deflection-delay.html): *"In a very real sense, the delay experienced by light passing a massive object is responsible for the deflection of the light".*

[image]

We refer to this as gravitational lensing, and it isn't unlike ordinary lensing, which involves refraction. See [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/refr.html), where Rod Nave says this: *"Refraction is the bending of a wave when it enters a medium where its speed is different".* Gravity doesn't do the bending, electromagnetism does.

> Like a machine invented by Nikola Tesla?

What machine? We can bend light with lenses or via diffraction. And light can "bend by itself", see [this article](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2012/04/light-bends-itself). Or we can "tie light in knots" see [this article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/7012307/A-team-of-scientists-managed-to-tie-light-in-knots.html). You might say none of these really count, but the bottom line is that light can and does change direction, and at the root of it there's some kind of fundamental force at work.

> and that machine actually bends em waves and makes any thing behind it invisible...

There's various reportage of "cloaking", such as [this](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2014/jun/09/new-invisibility-cloak-works-for-diffuse-light).

> can any force field bend em waves??

Yes. And the Faraday effect [rotates them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect). But perhaps what you're looking for here is pair production. It take only 511keV worth of electromagnetic energy to bend a photon into a closed "spinor" path. After which you can perform electron diffraction to demonstrate the wave nature of matter, or annihilation with the positron to reverse the process. Whereupon the electromagnetic energy resumes its linear path.

Answer (score 0):

Note : Gravity doesn't "bend" light. Light always travels in a straight path. The thing that "bends" is spacetime and light travels on straight paths in it.

Your answer depends on the definition of bending. If bending involves scattering, then even matter distributions that have coupling with electromagnetic field can bend light, eg refraction etc as pointed out in one comment. As pointed out in another comment, strong interaction affects EM with loop amplitudes. In weak interactions too, interaction amplitudes can be constructed. But whether you consider scattering with bending is purely your choice.

EDIT:
The most likely conclusion in my opinion is what igael says, a material of high refractive index with cleverly cut edges. Maybe it works on principles of refraction and total internal reflection and not using other forces, for Tesla would first have to tinker with physics at the nuclear level in order to understand strong force and weak force. The thing is, even the model of atom was discovered very late in his time, and he would have to understand it first and then go on to smaller nuclear scales to study other forces. Then afterwards, gain control over these forces and use them to manipulate light. This sounds pretty unreasonable. And given the technological capacity Tesla had, he would have exploited many other important things on this way IMO, like nuclear energy etc. As a result the only conclusion is that he didn't use different forces, but might have cleverly used refraction and total internal reflection in his model, if any.

Comment: the OP asks for bending light, not bending space :) it's ok for me

Comment: @igael i thought there was an apparent misunderstanding by OP in assuming that gravity bends light.